# Chakra UI color mode is stuck in dark mode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, darkmode, chakra-ui

I am currently trying to add a Color Mode Switch to my Vite React app using Chakra UI. Unfortunately I am not able to get the desired results.

When clicking a switch to toggle the color mode it changes from light to dark mode, but if you click the switch again, it will not render in light mode.

main.tsx

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!);
root.render(
  <>
    <ColorModeScript initialColorMode={customTheme.config.initialColorMode} />
    <React.StrictMode>
      <ChakraProvider
        theme={customTheme}
      >
        <BrowserRouter>
          <AuthProvider>  //<- custom provider
            <App />
          </AuthProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </ChakraProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </>
);
```

theme.ts

```
import {
  extendTheme,
  ThemeConfig,
  withDefaultColorScheme,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";

const config: ThemeConfig = {
  initialColorMode: "light",
  useSystemColorMode: false,
};

export const customTheme = extendTheme(
  {
    config,
    colors: {
      brand: {
        50: "#FFB7B1",
        100: "#FF9E98",
        200: "#FF3E30",
        300: "#FB1100",
        400: "#C80D00",
        500: "#930A00",
        600: "#890900",
        700: "#7F0800",
        800: "#740800",
        900: "#6A0700",
      },
    },
  },
  withDefaultColorScheme({ colorScheme: "brand" })
);
```

Settings.tsx

```js
export const Settings = () => {
  const { colorMode, toggleColorMode } = useColorMode();

  const handleDarkModeChange = () => {
    toggleColorMode();
  };

return (
    <Container marginTop={8} width="full">
      <VStack spacing={6}>
        <Flex width="full">
          <BackButton />
          <Heading flex={1}>Einstellungen</Heading>
        </Flex>

        <InputGroup size="lg">
          <InputLeftElement pointerEvents="none">
            <Icon as={MagnifyingGlass} />
          </InputLeftElement>
          <Input type="text" placeholder="Suche" onChange={handleSearch} />
        </InputGroup>
        <List width="full" spacing={6}>
          <ListItem>
            <InstallButton />
          </ListItem>

          //does not toggle correctly
           <ListItem>
            <FormControl
             display="flex"
             alignItems="center"
             justifyContent="space-between"
            >
              <FormLabel htmlFor="dark-theme-switch" margin={0} fontSize="lg">
                Dark Theme
              </FormLabel>

              <Switch
                id="dark-theme-switch"
                size="lg"
                onChange={handleDarkModeChange}
              />
            </FormControl>
          </ListItem>

        </List>
      </VStack>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found a fix. Issue was not related to chakra-ui but my implementation handling state and rendering this state

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).